# What are good ways of monitoring server status?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, monitoring, status

I have a central load balancing server and several application servers running on Apache Tomcat. The load balancing server receives request and forwards them to the application servers in round robin fashion. If one these application servers goes down, the load balancing server should stop forwarding requests to it.

My current solution for this is to ping the application servers every few minutes and if I don't receive a response, remove them from a list of available servers. Is there a better way to monitor the status of these servers? Should I ping more often or should the application servers constantly inform the load balancing server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute a null transaction on it regularly. Pinging really isn't enough, it only exercises the TCP/IP stack, and I have seen operating systems in states where TCP/IP was up but no applications and not even part of the OS stack itself. Executing a transaction exercises everything. Include the database in the null transaction.

Comment: Would a null transaction be a simple GET that just responds 200 OK?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis That would be the null-est transaction possible, but as I said above something that involves the database would be more comprehensive, say a SELECT ... LIMIT 1.

Comment: My Servlet already performs a MySQL "START TRANSACTION" query on the database right before it handles the request, so I'm already covered. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure your server isn DDOS attrack protected , if the depends on you application connection avg time edit keep alive time

Then you should study about  precock mpm , i think it will give you best solution